Stripe /create-checkout-session POST throws 500 error
I'm having a problem with integrating a redirect to the stripe-hosted page where the POST request keeps throwing 500 error and I have no idea why. The keys for both the front and back end are correct.
I keep getting
POST
http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session
error in my frontend.
I have a feeling it's the my response object is configured but can't confirm.
This is the frontend function for makepayment


const makePayment = async () => {
    try {
      const stripePromise = loadStripe(
        {process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}"
      );
  
      const stripe = await stripePromise;
  
      const body = {
        products: cart,
      };
  
      const response = await fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }
  
      const session = await response.json();
      if (session.error) {
        throw new Error(session.error);
      }
  
      const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: session.id,
      });
  
      if (result.error) {
        throw new Error(result.error.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Payment failed:", error);
      toast({
        title: "Payment error",
        description: error.message,
        status: "error",
        duration: 9000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  };



And here is my express backend


//stripe
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET);

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const { products } = req.body;
  console.log(products)

  if (!products || !Array.isArray(products) || products.length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "No products provided." });
  }

  try {
    const lineItems = products.map((product) => ({
      price_data: {
        currency: "cad",
        product_data: {
          name: product.name,
          images: product.image ? [product.image] : undefined, // Ensure this is a valid URL if uncommented
        },
        unit_amount: Math.round(product.price * 100), // Ensure price is in cents
      },
      quantity: product.qty,
    }));

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: lineItems,
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/OrderSuccessScreen`, // Use dynamic host
      cancel_url: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/OrderCancelScreen`, // Use dynamic host
    });

    res.redirect(303, session.url);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});




A 500 http response indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. You'll want to step through your backend code step by step to figure out which line of code is causing this issue as the first troubleshooting step.
